# Testing user_controller that needs an Account set up for @create_attrs

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I used `phx.gen.json` to create `Account` and `User`. A `User` has `account_id`, so an associated `Account` is required for a `User` to exist.

In the `user_controller_test.exs` that was generated, I have the following:

```
@create_attrs %{
    first_name: "some first name",
    last_name: "some last name"
  }

describe "create user" do
  test "renders user when data is valid", %{conn: conn} do
    conn = post(conn, Routes.user_path(conn, :create), user: @create_attrs)
    assert %{"id" => id} = json_response(conn, 201)["data"]

    conn = get(conn, Routes.user_path(conn, :show, id))

    assert %{
              "id" => ^id,
              "first_name" => "some first name"
            } = json_response(conn, 200)["data"]
  end

  test "renders errors when data is invalid", %{conn: conn} do
    conn = post(conn, Routes.user_path(conn, :create), user: @invalid_attrs)
    assert json_response(conn, 422)["errors"] != %{}
  end
end
```

However, in order to create a User, an Account must already exist and there is a database level constraint that the `User.account_id` references `Account.id`.

Reading the docs, it seems I can use the `setup` block, but I am struggling to figure out how I can get an account created here. It seems simple enough to do but not sure how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

Often I use the `setup` block to checkout the PostGres repo: this is important because it wraps all the database actions in a transaction that can be aborted when the test is complete.  Consider something the general structure of this:

```
defmodule MyApp.MyTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: false

  alias MyApp.Repo
  alias Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox

  setup do
    Sandbox.checkout(Repo)
  end

  describe "create user" do
   test "renders user when data is valid", %{conn: conn} do
    # Arrange
    {:ok, account} = create_account() # <-- insert necessary records here

    # Act
    result = create_user(%{
      first_name: "some first name",
      last_name: "some last name",
      account_id: account.id
    })
    
    # Assert
    assert {:ok, _} = result
   end

  end
end
```

You may decide to rely on database seeds for your tests or you may decide to use a fixture-generation tool like `ex_machina` to help facilitate the easy creation of unique records for each test.  Things can get really sticky if one test creates records that end up confusing the expected results of other tests, so using a library like `ex_machina` can help ensure the records involved in each test are unique, but it does take longer to set up.